# Apache TOP command time format?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, time, top

When running `top` on an Apache server, what is the time format for the output?

For instance, is it `minute:second.second`?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMbcf.png

**Edit:**

I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04 and the header of the column is `TOP+`.

Comment: This is totally not about apache but rether about your OS and bundled `top` version. Can you please specify what OS are you running on this server and fix tags? And yes, most probably this is `minute:second:fractions_of_second`.

Comment: @kworr Apologies, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

You've omitted the column header line, and you also don't say what operating system you're using, but I'm assuming Linux and that the heading for the CPU time column is `TIME+`.  From the Linux `top` manpage:

> ```
>    29. TIME  --  CPU Time
>        Total CPU time the task  has  used  since  it  started.   When
>        'Cumulative  mode'  is On, each process is listed with the cpu
>        time that it and its dead  children  have  used.   You  toggle
>        'Cumulative  mode'  with  'S',  which  is  both a command-line
>        option and an interactive command.  See  the  'S'  interactive
>        command for additional information regarding this mode.
>
>    30. TIME+  --  CPU Time, hundredths
>        The  same  as  'TIME', but reflecting more granularity through
>        hundredths of a second.
> ```

So the format in that column is `minutes:seconds.hundredths-of-seconds`.

Comment: Thank you, with that being the case, isn't 16 minutes awfully long for an Apache process? The time is for a process, not a session, correct?

Comment: Correct -- but it depends how long your process has been running.  If your Apache instance has been up for two years, then 16 minutes looks quite good :)

Comment: What do you mean by if my Apache instance has been up for two years? Also, my CPU has always been at about 100%, could these long processes be the cause for that? If so, can I set a limit for how long these processes can run for?

Comment: As in: Apache was started two years ago and never restarted, so its processes' CPU times would just get bigger and bigger as time passed.  You don't want to set a limit, you want to investigate why 100% CPU is being used by Apache.  That shouldn't be happening.